# Add editable listbox in Glade

Tags: listbox, glade

I use Glade to create GUI, but can't figure out how to insert `listbox` from the side panel! I can see that a `GtkListStore` could be created but how to make an editable `listbox` from that?

I've found that it could be done through adding `GtkTreeView` structure with the specified `GtkListStore` pattern. I did some rows this way, but can't put entries in the cells. The cells are inactive and I cannot add text to them!

Answer (score 0):

I post my answer in case someone else struggle with this issue.

The way is to create `GtkListStore` and to assign it to a `GtkTreeView` with editable cells (see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/Editable_Cells) and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/Miscellaneous)). Example of editable cells of a `GtkTreeView` is given [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/editable_cells.c), in the function:

```
static void cell_edited (GtkCellRendererText *cell,
                         const gchar         *path_string,
                         const gchar         *new_text,
                         gpointer             data)
```

Also use the c++ functions `int atoi(const char * str)` and `double stod(const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0)` in case the cell type of the `GtkListStore` is `gint` or `gdouble` respectively.